# BitArray returns bits the wrong way around?

Tags: c#, enumeration, bitarray

This code:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { 7 });
foreach (bool bit in bits)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bit ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Gives me the following output:

```
11100000
```

Shouldn't it be the other way around? Like this:

```
00000111
```

I am aware that there is little and big endian, although those terms only refer to the position of bytes. As far as I know, they don't affect bits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [documentation for BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a.aspx) states:

> The first byte in the array represents bits 0 through 7, the second
>   byte represents bits 8 through 15, and so on. The Least Significant
>   Bit of each byte represents the lowest index value: " bytes [0] & 1"
>   represents bit 0, " bytes [0] & 2" represents bit 1, " bytes [0] & 4"
>   represents bit 2, and so on.

When indexing bits, the convention is to start at the least significant end, which is the right side when written in binary notation.  However, when enumerating the array, you start at index 0, so they are printed out left-to-right instead of right-to-left.  That's why it looks backwards.

For example, the word 01011010 00101101 (90 45) would be indexed as:

```
 0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  -  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1
-----------------------    -----------------------
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8     7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

And you would pass it to the constructor as `new byte[] { 45, 90 }` since you pass it least-significant first.  When printed out, it would display in index order as: `1011010001011010`, which is the reverse of the original binary notation.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is not explicit about it, but I guess the iterator iterates from the LSB to the MSB. Sound reasonable to me (personally!), unless you are printing out the bits. I had a look at [BitArray.GetEnumerator Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.getenumerator.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

No it's a bit array, not a numeric value represented as bits.

It's just like any regular array with some methods added for bit operations.  Just like if you had an array of int.  You wouldn't expect it to be in the reverse order, it just takes it position by position.

Eg:

Numbers (in a byte) converted to a `BitArray` would come out like:

```
2 = 01000000
5 = 10100000
8 = 00010000
```

etc.

It just stores the position of the value but not relative as you would except from a binary numeric value.

Here is a link describing the constructor you are using:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3d1dwck.aspx

The key point is:

> The number in the first values array element represents bits 0 through
>   31, the second number in the array represents bits 32 through 63, and
>   so on. **The Least Significant Bit of each integer represents the lowest
>   index value**: " values [0] & 1" represents bit 0, " values [0] & 2"
>   represents bit 1, " values [0] & 4" represents bit 2, and so on.