# How to fill a BitArray so that copying it to a byte will work

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitarray

Please consider this (non-homework) exercise of converting a slash-notation (e.g. 24, 30) to a subnet mask.

**When I copy a `BitArray` to `byte[]`, the internal ordering of the `BitArray` leads to incorrect output.**

For instance, with an input of `numberOfSetBits=24`, `ToString()` should return `255.255.255.0` (this works because the bits are symmetrical).
However, an input of `30` results in `255.255.255.63` instead of the expected `255.255.255.252`.
Yes, I realize that [that's just the way a BitArray handles it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066831/bitarray-returns-bits-the-wrong-way-around) (there's an [old discussion](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/wrong-bitarray-copyto-might-have-posted-twice-sorry-t1366528.html) about the issue, unfortunately without a *solution*, just a never-ending argument over why one ordering would be better).

But how, for the love of god, can I get this code to treat `1111 1100` (=252) for what it is instead of mangling it to `0011 1111` (=63)? I believe I'll have to change the order in which I'm adding the bits in the first place, but I can't get it to work.

```
public class SubnetMask
{
    private byte[] parts = new byte[4];

    public static SubnetMask FromSlash(int numberOfSetBits)
    {
        BitArray bits = new BitArray(32);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSetBits; i++)
        {
            bits[i] = true;
        }
        return new SubnetMask(bits);
    }

    private SubnetMask(BitArray bits)
    {
        bits.CopyTo(parts, 0);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(".", parts);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Mehrdad nice one- chalk up another class I didn't know existed :-)

Comment: @ChrisShain: lol. I think you mean `struct`. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `BitArray`, you can create the mask from shifting an integer, and use `BitConverter.GetBytes` to get it as bytes:

```
public static SubnetMask FromSlash(int numberOfSetBits) {
  int mask = numberOfSetBits == 0 ? 0 : -1 << (32 - numberOfSetBits);
  byte[] bits = BitConverter.GetBytes(mask);
  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bits);
  return new SubnetMask(bits);
}
```

Comment: interestingly, it doesn't work for an input of 0. Any explanation why left shifting an integer by 32 bits leaves me with the original integer?

Comment: @codesparkle: Ah... the shift only uses five bits of the second operand, i.e. `x << (y & 0x1f)`. "The count is masked to 5 bits": http://jsimlo.sk/docs/cpu/index.php/shl.html So you need to do an extra check for that.

Comment: that's annoying.. I wonder why it has to be limited that way. could you update your answer to reflect that? e.g. `numberOfSetBits == 0 ? 0 : -1 << (32 - numberOfSetBits)`

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this just be fixed by doing:

```
int bitPlace = 32;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSetBits; i++)
{
    bits[--bitPlace] = true;
}
```

This sets the high-order bits (rather than the low-order bits).  The reasoning here is precisely what is mentioned in the answer you linked- BitArray stores the least-significant digits in the lowest index, so the bit array `11111000000000` below is [indexed] thus:

```
(Most Significant)                  (Least Significant)
 1    1    1    1    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[14] [13] [11] [10] [9] [8] [7] [6] [5] [4] [3] [2] [1] [0]
```

Comment: this does indeed work, however it requires this change in the `SubnetMask` constructor: `parts = parts.Reverse().ToArray();` to fix the ordering of the bytes.

Comment: thanks for your effort though - I upvoted, but I can only set one post as the answer.